# Unless I play first music and pause it, the second music doesn't load when using glob() in php

Tags: php, html

When a user search for a music, the site browses all music in a folder using `glob()` and load it on the page by looping all results. But unless I play and pause the first music, the second doesn't load. The code is:

```
<?php 
$the_count=-1;
$data=$_POST['search-box'];
foreach (glob("uploaded_music/*.mp3") as $filename) {
if(preg_match("/$data/i", $filename)){
$the_count++;
$the_file[$the_count]=$filename;
}
?>

<!--I have few html codes in between-->

<?php
$the_count=-1;
foreach ($the_file as $key => $value):
$the_count++;
?>

<div class="music-player-edited">  
<?php echo str_replace("uploaded_music/", "", $the_file[$the_count])); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $the_file[$the_count]; ?>" download>Download</a>
<audio id="player2" src="<?php echo $the_file[$the_count] ?>" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: note- since this is in a loop, you will have `count($the_file)` number of `id="player2"`. I don't think that is the issue, but it is invalid html as `id`s are to be unique.

Comment: I had that music player plugin. So every time I should display the music player, I have to give the same id. What would be the better option than that?